# Accessing a Windows 2012 Server box via Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

We just powered up a new Dell server running Windows 2012 R2 Standard. Right now, it's a standalone machine, connected to our local Intranet.

I am trying to connect to the machine using Remote Desktop but nothing seems to work. The Administrator account has been enabled as a Remote Desktop User. There is no domain defined.

When we try to connect using Remote Desktop and the explicit IP address of this box, then entering Administrator as the username and the admin's password, we get the following error message:

Remote Desktop Connection cannot verify the identity of the computer that you want to connect to.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Dan

Comment: We worked out the answer. Turns out I was running an older version of the Remote Desktop Client (2.1.0) on my Mac; I needed to upgrade to the latest version (8.0 - big jump there) and then it just started working. 2.1 is not compatible with Windows 2012 R2 Server

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead of writing a comment with the answer.